# Redirect all URL except one query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have 2 domain `mcleancenter.org` and `aldentheatre.org`,Both pointing to one directory. I want to redirect all `URLs` which don't have `"alden-theatre"` to `mcleancenter.org`. And all URLs which have `"alden-theatre"` in `URLs` should redirect to `aldentheatre.org`.

For example:

- `/about` should redirect to `mcleancenter.org/about`
- `/contact` should redirect to `mcleancenter.org/contact`
- `/alden-theatre` should redirect to `aldentheatre.org/alden-theatre`
- `/alden-theatre/perfomance` should redirect to `aldentheatre.org/alden-theatre/perfomance`

Any Help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Which server are you using?

You could do it in any case by putting an Apache Server as proxy 'before' any server you are using. You could then redirect the requests using [mod_reqwirte](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/).

Comment: I have shared hosting, so I don't have access for appache server.

Answer (score 0):

As all urls redirecting to `mcleancenter.org` just redirect

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^alden-theatre(.*) http://www.aldentheatre.org/alden-theatre$1 [R]
```

Hope this will help

Comment: It is redirecting url which have alden-theatre in URL to http://www.aldentheatre.org/alden-theatre$1, but then it is not redirecting URL http://www.aldentheatre.org/about-us to  www.mcleancenter.org/about-us